# How to plot "graph paths"

Tags: r, igraph

I spent some time researching previous stackexchange posts on how to find "paths" and "shortest paths" between points in graphs. However, I have not been able to figure out how to plot these "paths"

I was able to create some fake data, create a graph and determine "paths" between different points:

```
#create some data
Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
    
    "Node_A" = c("John", "John", "John", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
    "Node_B" = c("Claude", "Peter", "Tim", "Tim", "Claude", "Henry", "Kevin", "Claude", "Tim", "Henry", "Claude")
)


#load library
library(igraph)


#create graph
graph_file <- data.frame(Data_I_Have$Node_A, Data_I_Have$Node_B)
colnames(graph_file) <- c("Data_I_Have$Node_A", "Data_I_Have$Node_B")
graph <- graph.data.frame(graph_file, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)

#path analysis
path_a = all_simple_paths(graph, "Claude", "Adam")
path_b = all_simple_paths(graph, "Claude", c("Adam", "Kevin"))
sp=get.all.shortest.paths(graph, "Claude", "Kevin")
```

However, I have not been able to plot one of these "paths"

```
#attempt to plot one of the paths
plot(sp$res[1])

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Do these have to be converted into an "igraph object"?

```
igraph::subgraph(sp$res[1])

Error in igraph::subgraph(sp$res[1]) : Not a graph object
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want the plot to look like? To you only want to draw the nodes in the path?

Comment: @MrFlick : thank you for your edits and reply. I am trying to get something like this: https://imgur.com/a/iGH7pdV      Is this possible?

Comment: take a look and google TSP

Comment: The how about `plot(induced_subgraph(graph, sp$res[[1]]))`. Note that double brackets are important here.

Comment: @MrFlick: wow! this works! is the induced_subgraph statement necessary?

Comment: Yes, that's what's actually subsetting the graph to just the points you are interested in.

Comment: thanks again for all your help. If I understand correctly, if you say  : a = induced_subgraph(graph, sp$res[[1]]) .... you should now be able to plot "a" using the visNetwork library

Comment: is there any chance either of you knows how to change colors for graph nodes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925384/r-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-specific-point